# iOS 6: Trying to select from 2 databases from different paths

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have two databases.

1. ch_coins.db is read-only data for tableview in [NSBundle mainBundle].
2. User_data.sqlite in Documents

I try to combine select from both databases and fill data to object. My method is like that:

```
-(NSMutableArray*)returnSubCountries
{
NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]
                  stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *userDB = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:user_data];


NSMutableArray *subCountiresArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{

    /*const char *sqlSubCountries="SELECT subCountryID,subCountryName,subCountryComment,image,priority,hasRegions,navigationKey\
    FROM subCountries\
    ORDER BY priority ASC";*/
    const char *sqlSubCountries="SELECT subCountryID,subCountryName,subCountryComment,image,priority,hasRegions,navigationKey,usdb.quantity\
    attach database 'userDB' as usdb\
    INNER JOIN usdb on subCountries.subCountryID=usdb.refID\
    FROM subCountries\
    ORDER BY priority ASC";
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    int sqlResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlSubCountries, -1, &statement, NULL);
    if ( sqlResult== SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            SubCountry *sbCountryObj=[[SubCountry alloc]init];
            sbCountryObj.subCountryID=sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
            char *subCountryName=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
            char *subCountryComment=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);
            char *image=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3);
            sbCountryObj.priority=sqlite3_column_int(statement, 4);
            sbCountryObj.hasRegions=(sqlite3_column_int(statement, 5)==1);
            sbCountryObj.navigationKey=sqlite3_column_int(statement, 6);
            sbCountryObj.quantity=sqlite3_column_int(statement, 7);
            sbCountryObj.subCountryName=(subCountryName)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:subCountryName]: @"";
            sbCountryObj.subCountryComment=(subCountryComment)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:subCountryComment]: @"";
            sbCountryObj.image=(image)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:image]: @"";
            [subCountiresArr addObject:sbCountryObj];
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
}
else
{
    //[self dbConnectionError];
}
return subCountiresArr;
}
```

I must be doing something wrong. any help is much appreciated. Thanx.

EDIT:

```
-(NSMutableArray*)returnSubCountries
{
NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]
                  stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *userDB = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:user_data];


NSMutableArray *subCountiresArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{

    /*const char *sqlSubCountries="SELECT subCountryID,subCountryName,subCountryComment,image,priority,hasRegions,navigationKey\
    FROM subCountries\
    ORDER BY priority ASC";*/
    NSString *userDBName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"attach database '%@' as usdb", userDB];
    const char *sqlAttachedDatabase = [userDBName UTF8String];

    const char *sqlSubCountries="SELECT subCountryID,subCountryName,subCountryComment,image,priority,hasRegions,navigationKey,usdb.quantity\
    sqlAttachedDatabase userDB as usdb\
    INNER JOIN usdb on subCountries.subCountryID=usdb.refID\
    FROM subCountries\
    ORDER BY priority ASC";
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    int sqlResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlSubCountries, -1, &statement, NULL);
    if ( sqlResult== SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            SubCountry *sbCountryObj=[[SubCountry alloc]init];
            sbCountryObj.subCountryID=sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
            char *subCountryName=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
            char *subCountryComment=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);
            char *image=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3);
            sbCountryObj.priority=sqlite3_column_int(statement, 4);
            sbCountryObj.hasRegions=(sqlite3_column_int(statement, 5)==1);
            sbCountryObj.navigationKey=sqlite3_column_int(statement, 6);
            sbCountryObj.quantity=sqlite3_column_int(statement, 7);
            sbCountryObj.subCountryName=(subCountryName)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:subCountryName]: @"";
            sbCountryObj.subCountryComment=(subCountryComment)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:subCountryComment]: @"";
            sbCountryObj.image=(image)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:image]: @"";
            [subCountiresArr addObject:sbCountryObj];
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"%s: prepare failed: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
}
else
{
    //[self dbConnectionError];
}
return subCountiresArr;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're specifying the database path as `userDB` in your SQL, but that's not the name of the database file. That is, the name of the variable that has the full path name in it, but you presumably actually have to build your SQL with that filename. For example:

```
NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"attach database '%@' as usdb", userDB];
const char *sqlAttachedDatabase = [sql UTF8String];
```

Execute that. Then, as a separate statement, you can execute your SELECT SQL that uses the `usdb` alias. And when you're done, detach the database.

Also, I notice that you're checking to see if the result is `SQLITE_OK` (which is good). But you're not showing any diagnostic information if it's not. For example, your SQL is wrong, but you're not showing a meaningful error message. Thus, if your `sqlite3_prepare_v2` fails to return `SQLITE_OK`, you should:

```
NSLog(@"%s: prepare failed: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
```

If you do this when you have an error, you'll be able to figure out what's wrong. Without that, you're flying blind.

---

A working example, where my "author" database is in the bundle, and my "book" database is in `Documents`:

```
int rc;

NSString *docsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSString *bookFilename = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"book.sqlite"];

NSString *authorFilename = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"author" ofType:@"sqlite"];

sqlite3 *database;

if ((rc = sqlite3_open([authorFilename UTF8String], &database)) != SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSLog(@"%s: open failed: %s (%d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database), rc);
    return;
}

NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"attach database '%@' as userdb;", bookFilename];

if ((rc = sqlite3_exec(database, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL)) != SQLITE_OK)
    NSLog(@"%s: attach failed: %s (%d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database), rc);

sqlite3_stmt *statement;

sql = @"select book.*, author.* from userdb.book inner join author on author_id = book_author_id;";

if ((rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL)) != SQLITE_OK)
    NSLog(@"%s: prepare failed: %s (%d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database), rc);

while ((rc = sqlite3_step(statement)) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
    // do whatever you want row by row
    NSLog(@"Row");
}

if (rc != SQLITE_DONE)
    NSLog(@"%s: step failed: %s (%d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database), rc);

sqlite3_finalize(statement);

sql = @"detach database userdb;";

if ((rc = sqlite3_exec(database, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL)) != SQLITE_OK)
    NSLog(@"%s: detach failed: %s (%d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database), rc);

sqlite3_close(database);
```

Comment: Thank you Rob. You gave me a valuable experience right now, but sorry, I still not get it how to attach it in in my sql query.

Comment: edit is ready. Frankly I don't have an idea how to execute this statement.

Comment: @Nathan Just call `sqlite3_exec(database, sqlAttachedDatabase, NULL, NULL, NULL);`

Comment: Done. But how to handle in this spot? INNER JOIN usdb on subCountries.subCountryID=usdb.refID\

Comment: @Nathan That's separate issue. That SQL is incorrect. It's hard for me to fix given that I don't know your table names, but you're conflating the database name and table name. Look at the examine in my revised answer which has an example. My SQL is: `"select book.*, author.* from userdb.book inner join author on author_id = book_author_id;`", where the `book` table is in the `userdb` database. The database is referenced only in the `FROM` clause, but elsewhere, I just refer to the table name. Also note, do not have the `ATTACH` command in your `SELECT` SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You should do the following:

1. Run SQL "attach database 'full db path' as usdb", where "full db path" is full path to database file
2. Prepare and execute SELECT statement (remove "attach database ..." from it)
3. Detach database when it's not needed "detach database 'full db path'"